# How to have a Splitview in a tab bar with storyboard?

Tags: ios6, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller, ipad

I have seen IPad apps like the new Amazon app that have a split view as a tab in a tab bar. I have tried to make one like that by starting with a master-detail template and adding a tab bar and/or a tab bar controller to it, then I tried a Tabbed template and added a split view and/or a split view controller to it, I even tried one from scratch and still no luck. I know it can be done and approved by apple because I'm starting to see more of them on the app store.

Can any one help find a way to make a app like this with storyboards preferably?

[this is a screenshot of what I would like to do](http://i1351.photobucket.com/albums/p787/techd84/ScreenShot2013-07-20at40040PM_zps24f4ab95.png)

Comment: what problems are you getting when you tried these?

Comment: ive check the code in the app delegate what exactly is your error when trying to add a tab controller as long as you make a connection from tab controller  to the navigation controller everything should work fine.

Comment: 2013-07-21 22:48:32.509 t[7310:11303] Unknown class DetailViewController in Interface Builder file. 

this is a tabview tremp with a slipview in it

Comment: sounds like you dragged the class into another project and you were able to set it up as the class for a nib but xcode isnt told to compile it at run time/ you may have not selected add to project when you dragged it as well.

Comment: [github link](https://github.com/techd884/test-part-4) the unknown class error was from not clicking adding it to the project. it sees it now as a tab temp with a split view in it but as soon as I make the tableview the master I get a "terminate called throwing an exception" error but if I don't make it the master it wont populate. I'm not sure what to do now every way I try to set it I get a different error

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your using templates from apple and they have setup in app delegate file for what the root view controller should be. In both situations you present you change this. Using a master detail template you will have this in your app delegate

```
  UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    MasterViewController *controller = (MasterViewController *)navigationController.topViewController;
    controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```

and then you try to make the root view a tab bar controller and that's where you are getting errors. I just did a test and pretty much cleared everything in app delegate and changed masterviewcontroller in storybuilder to a regular tableviewcontroller class and everything loaded up. If it's not exactly what you need for a small application you are better off starting with a empty application for learning purposes and because it's better to know where everything is because you are the one that created it.